# How can escape html special chars of a string with xslt?

Tags: xslt

I have the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="questionExplanation">
<span class="questionExplanation">
  <xsl:value-of select="node()" />
</span>
```

The value of `node()` is "enter a number <= 5" 
I need to escape the `<` to `&lt;` (And all others htmls special chars.

How can i do that?
Im using xslt 2.0

Thanks!

Comment: This should be done automatically by default. Have you looked at the output HTML?

Comment: i have this line on top of my xslt `<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" version="4.0"/>`

Comment: No, I mean have you looked at the actual output it produces? That line there looks correct.

Comment: `<span class="questionExplanation">Enter number, must be <= 1 1<sup>st</sup> line metastatic.</span>`

Comment: in the original xml i have the following       `<questionExplanation>Enter number, must be &lt;= {[53]} 1&lt;sup&gt;st&lt;/sup&gt; line metastatic.</questionExplanation>`

Comment: Are you by any chance using `disable-output-escaping="true"` anywhere in your XSLT?